# Issue importing numerical data with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

thank you for taking the time. I have a excel file thats being read into a dataframe using pandas read_excel. The original data file looks like this:

| Contract_NO | PREMIUMS | UnderWriting_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 91 | -1108773.10 | 2006 |
| 91 | 15813189.34 | 2007 |
| 91 | 3975973.48 | 2008 |
| 91 | 5770016.41 | 2009 |

And im able to load it with almost no problems. However, when i check the data in python only one row has an incorrect premium. For example lets assume that row is for year 2007 and in pandas the premium amount is ***5182024.08***. This is without any tranformations, calculations or anything done to the dataframe. Im extremly stumped as to why.

The code im using to read in the data is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/tkmwangi/Downloads/Non-Life Data.xlsx')

data = df.loc['df[Contract_NO'] == 91]

data
```

I've tried to convert the file to csv and the same error still persisits.

Comment: Unable to reproduce w/o the original file.

Comment: I still could not understand what error, you can be more explicit. This could be a problem with data collection. This entry was incorrect. Since it just read the file. If it's a problem like this, please send a print of data.info(), together with your updated explanation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: df.loc['df[Contract_NO'] == 91] should be df.loc[df['Contract_NO'] == 91]